# Display query output on top but query execution at the bottom

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have this code. What this code do is it will display query output at the top and bottom. Query execution is at bottom.

```
<span><?php echo mysqli_num_rows($result) ?></span>

//my other code here

//query database
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT brand, url,...

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row['brand'];
echo $row['url'];
}
```

I have few constraint which is I cannot put my query at the top and multiple `select` query. How do you suggest I solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand. You want to echo a result before you've ran the query?

Comment: yes.. that's what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

You cant call mysqli_num_rows unless you query database.

But for your solution, Ir you want to show number of records on the top of page?

You can call query before you print mysqli_num_rows and then recall when needed at bottom like displayed here:

```
<?php //query database
$result1 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT brand, url,... ?>
<span><?php echo mysqli_num_rows($result1) ?></span>

//my other code here

//query database
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT brand, url,...

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row['brand'];
echo $row['url'];
}
```